# How to add nosql ( mongodb ) support for jsf 2.0 project?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, mongodb, morphia

i am writing a web application with jsf 2.0 and using primefaces framework. 
i want to use mongodb as my database and "getting started" guide for mongodb is just explaining the basic java usage. 
I did make it work with "public static void main(String[] args)" but unfortunately not for my web application.

it would help a lot if u could help with one of these;

- "the mongodb connection for jsf 2.0" in a pseudo code  or
- where should the connection be defined in the project? (xml,java)
- will i need any other framework to make it work ? (looked little bit to morphia)

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to go with [JSF 2.0 and Spring integration](http://xebee.xebia.in/2011/10/31/spring-jsf-integration-made-easy-clean-using-spring-annotations/), and along with this use [Spring Data MongoDB](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb)

using the above two integrations, you would be seamlessly integrate mongodb in your web app.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring framework, you can use [Spring Data MongoDB](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb). 
There is very good documentation to get you started.